# Carregar um DLL netstandard 2.1 em uma aplicação .NETFramework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#

Olá, tem um projeto feito em .NETFramework 4.7.2 que precisa via reflection accessar os CustomAttributes de uma DLL compilada em .netstandard 2.1. Estou utilizando a seguinte solução:

Abaixo um exemplo em um console application criada em .NETFramework 4.7.2:

```c#
private static System.Reflection.Assembly OnReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0\ref\netstandard2.1\netstandard.dll");
        
        return assembly;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    
    return null;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += OnReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve;

    Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"C:\DLLNETSTANDARD21.dll");

    var custom = CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(SampleAssembly);            
}
```

Mas tenho recebido o seguinte erro:

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' because the parent does not exist.'`

Não encontrei outra maneira de fazer isso e ou resolver esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode consumir, a partir do .NET Framework, nenhum projeto/dll escrito em .NET Standard 2.1. Dê uma olhada na tabela do [Suporte à implementação do .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

> NET Framework não dá suporte a .NET Standard 2,1. Para obter mais informações, consulte o [anúncio do .NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/)